# Trying to push to detail view with Xcode 4.2 iOS 5 from UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, ios5, storyboard

I have a ViewController embedded in a NavigationController. The ViewController has a UIWebView that I'm trying to capture links from. I'm able to intercept the links, but when I try to push the link content to a detail page, it seems to be firing a new Controller but it's invisible. If I click a link for a second time (or if I just click a second link) I see a back button pop up, but again the actual content of the new ViewController is not visible.

Here is the log output for the first link click:

```
2011-11-07 10:38:27.526 WGGB[43875:f803] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:   <NSInternalInconsistencyException> Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  </Users/sonnyjitsu/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/4B3D5152-4EA5-4C84-BB22-A774FCB8B6A7/WGGB.app> (loaded)' with name 'Detail View'
```

As you can see, it's "loading" the new view, but I see nothing in the simulator. Then the second time I click the same link (or click a new link) I see this in the log:

```
2011-11-07 10:38:30.605 WGGB[43875:f803] url is http://www.blahblahblah.com/mobile
```

The method in question is this:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;
    NSRange page = [ urlString rangeOfString: @"/mobile" ];
    if (page.location == NSNotFound) {

        SingleStoryViewController *detailViewController = [[SingleStoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Detail View" bundle:nil];
        NSString *requestURL = 
            [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        [detailViewController.webView loadRequest:
            [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

        NSLog(@"url is %@", url);
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Top of my SingleStoryViewController.m

```
#import "SingleStoryViewController.h"

@implementation SingleStoryViewController

@synthesize webView;
```

Entire SingleStoryViewController.h
    #import

```
@interface SingleStoryViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

Here is a link to an image of my Xcode storyboard, for what it's worth: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7A6j.png

I've been working on this for a good 14 to 16 hours now and I'm finally saying 'uncle' and asking for help. Any help would be appreciated, I'm very new to iOS programming so I apologize if there is something really stupid I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see, it's "loading" the new view...

That's not what the error says. The error says this:

```
Could not load NIB in bundle: [...] with name 'Detail View'
```

I'd start by checking the name of the .xib file in your app -- it sounds like it may not match the name you're using in the code.

**Update:** Per comments below, it turns out that this is app uses storyboards and doesn't contain any .xib files, so it's no surprise that attempting to load a view controller from a .xib produces an error. The correct way to load a view controller from a storyboard, when necessary, is to use UIStoryboard's `-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method instead of UIViewController's `-initWithNibName:bundle:`.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused by this because I'm using storyboarding, so I don't have any .xibs in my project.

Comment: I'm still getting the hang of storyboards myself. Your error makes more sense now: since there aren't any .xibs, trying to load a view controller from a .xib obviously isn't going to work. Use UIStoryboard's `-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method to load a view controller from a storyboard, not `-initWithNibName:bundle:`. Usually, though, you just create segues in your storyboard instead of instantiating view controllers yourself.

Comment: Okay so I'm getting closer! I've changed the code that creates a ViewController Object to look like this: `SingleStoryViewController *detailViewController =
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SingleStoryView"];` But now I'm just getting a blank white screen, still no web content. I also had to click on my ViewController, click on the attributes inspector and change the identifier to SingleStoryView.

Comment: Caleb, if you modify your answer to include the info with  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: @SonnyParlin, I've updated the answer -- glad it got you a little closer to working code. The first thing I'd check in your web view is that the URL is correct and you have a network connection; after that, start looking at the info returned by the delegate methods. Perhaps we're straying into another question here...

Comment: I edited the original question to include the complete solution and I also accepted your answer thanks for your help!

Comment: @SonnyParlin, I'm glad to have helped. You're new to SO, so I'll point out that instead of adding your answer to your question, it's better to put it in an answer. You can either create your own answer, or you can update mine with your code. It's not a big deal -- just one of the quirks that makes SO what it is.