# storyboard and programic modal changes

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storyboard, xcode4.2

starting a new project and want to try using the storyboard feature of xcode 4.2.  i got the basics of how to do transitions within the story board, but how do i do it in the code (load a new view w/out the use of a button)?

do i just use the old method,

```
mapViewController *mapView = [[mapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mapViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
[self presentModalViewController:mapView animated:YES];
```

?

EDIT:

the old way doesn't work. also tried:

```
MapViewController *mapView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapView"];
self presentModalViewController:mapView animated:YES];
```

with no success.

Comment: What happens if you try?

Comment: haven't tried yet. i'll give it a whirl. i was just wondering if there is a new way to do it.

Comment: nope, doesn't load the view controller i made in storyboard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to push to detail view with Xcode 4.2 iOS 5 from UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038922/trying-to-push-to-detail-view-with-xcode-4-2-ios-5-from-uiwebview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i figured out the issue. i had uncommented the method "loadView" in the mapViewController so xcode did not use my storyboard layout.

also, both above methods do work to do a modal switch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load a view controller you made in a storyboard create a segue to this view controller, give it an identifier and call: [performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier%3asender%3a).